# Determine multiplicity of root $a$ of polynomial $\frac{x-a}{2}(f'(x) + f'(a)) - f(x) + f(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let's say that this is polynomial over some field for simplicity.

To be honest, I don't really know what trick we can use here. I know that if polynomial has multiplicity $k$ of some root, then it's derivative is equal to $k - 1$. But how can we use that fact to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't prove it, but the multeplicity of $x=a$ is $3$ if $\text{degree}(f(x))\ge 3 $

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the field is $R$. Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i(x-a)^i+b_0. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
F(x)&:=&\frac{x-a}{2}(f'(x) + f'(a)) - f(x) + f(a)\\
&=&\frac{x-a}{2}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^nib_i(x-a)^{i-1}+b_1\bigg] - \sum_{i=1}^nb_i(x-a)^i\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=3}^n\bigg[(i-2)b_i(x-a)^{i}-b_1(x-a)\bigg].
\end{eqnarray}
Suppose $n\ge3$. Then the multiplicity of $a$ of $F(x)$ is $1$ if $b_1\neq0$. If
$b_1=0$,then the multiplicity of $a$ of $F(x)$ is $k$ if
$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=k}^nb_i(x-a)^i+b_0, b_3=\cdots=b_{k-1}=0, b_k\neq0, k\ge3. $$
If $n=1,2$, $F(x)\equiv0$.

Comment: I have done many examples and the multiplicity is always $3$ when the degree of $f(x)$ if $\ge 3$

Comment: **Counterexample** $\ f = x^2,\ a = 0.\ $ There is an error in the 3rd line in the 2nd displayed equation set. it should be $\,-2g(x)\,$ not $\,-2(x-a)g(x)\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you for pointing this. I modified the answer.

Comment: But you didn't fix the error I mentioned, so the counterexample still holds.

Comment: Let me check. Thank you again.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I think this time is ok.